# How can I center these varied number of elements within a div?

Tags: html, css

I have a `<div>` with a number of sub-elements (which happen to be custom-sized buttons). It can have between 1 and 3 buttons.

**Example of HTML with 2 buttons:**

```
<div id="head">
    <div id="control-buttons-container">
        <button class="control-button">some button text</button>
        <button class="control-button">proceed with this button</button>
    </div>    
</div>
```

When there are 3 buttons, they fill the entire `<div>`, so it is not an issue. However, when there are 1 or 2 buttons, they need to be centered but I can't seem to accomplish this without introducing ridiculous conditional margins or something.

How can I modify this CSS so that `<div>` elements with 1 or 2 of these buttons show the buttons centered within the div?

**Please refer to the Fiddle:** https://jsfiddle.net/bf33wc6w/1/

**Edit:** With only 2 buttons, I don't want them to be spread out. I want them to be in the center with only ~2px between them similar to their spacing for when there are 3 buttons.

Comment: Also you are using elements with the same id in your HTML. I know this is an example, but I hope you aren't doing that in your HTML. Every ID needs to be unique. Generally speaking ids aren't for styling. HTML5 has very synamtic markup for things like header,footer,main, content, etc.

Comment: Also depending on the complexity of what you are doing, http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2015/07/14/quantity-ordering-with-css/

Comment: woops, the same id was just an oversight when making the demo, my bad.

Comment: See my updated [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31442171/483779) @AlbatrossCafe with more info, especially the additional suggestions regarding to the middle div position.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add these style rules:

```
#head, #body, #foot { text-align: center; }
#control-buttons-container { display: inline-block; }
```

As an aside, you shouldn't use the same id (control-buttons-container) multiple times in one document.  You should use a classname instead.

Updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/mr8e7kyt/

Comment: yeah, it was just an oversight when I was quickly drafting the example fiddle. thanks for this answer - it required the least amount of modification and achieves the goal exactly how I envisioned.

Answer (score 4):

You could set inline block on the items, with container set to text align center.

```
.control-buttons-container {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 0; /*fix inline block gap*/
}
.control-button {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    font-size: 12px; /*reset font size*/
}
```

<kbd>**[JSFIDDLE DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/skpex0ws/)**</kbd>

```css
.control-buttons-container {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 0; /*fix inline block gap*/
}
.control-button {
    background-color: #0E80B4;
    color: white;
    outline: none;
    height: 73px;
    width: 128px;
    margin: 3px 1.5px;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    font-size: 12px; /*reset font size*/
}
.control-button:hover {
    background-color: #3FA9DB;
}
#head, #body, #foot {
    border: 1px solid red;
    position: absolute;
    width: 396px;
    height: 80px;
    left: 0;
}
#head {
    top: 0;
}
#body {
    bottom: 50%;
    -ms-transform: translateY(50%);
    -webkit-transform: translateY(50%);
    transform: translateY(50%);
}
#foot {
    bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="head">
    <div class="control-buttons-container">
        <button class="control-button">some button text</button>
        <button class="control-button">proceed with this button</button>
        <button class="control-button">Seth Rollins, WWE Champion</button>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="body">
    <div class="control-buttons-container">
        <button class="control-button">proceed with this button</button>
        <button class="control-button">Seth Rollins, WWE Champion</button>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="foot">
    <div class="control-buttons-container">
        <button class="control-button">Seth Rollins, WWE Champion</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Updates:**

1. Fixed same id being used multiple times on a single page, which is in valid HTML - changed it to class.
2. Improved the position of middle block, make it to always stay in the middle more accurately - by using CSS `transform`.
3. Merged some duplicated CSS rules.

Answer (score 3):

Like this:https://jsfiddle.net/bf33wc6w/7/

All I did was change your float to none and the margin to auto for the left and right margin?

```
.control-button {
    background-color: #0E80B4;
    color: white;
    outline: none;
    border: none;
    height: 73px;
    width: 128px;
    margin: 3px auto;
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I guess I should specify that I don't want a ton of margin between each button if there is 2 (they should still be right next to each other with ~2px between them). I'll update the question

Comment: Ah, then @Pangloss has the better answer for what you want. I wasn't sure what you meant by centered.

Answer (score 1):

For the containers without 3 items you should remove the `float: left;` for the buttons inside it. Leave it for the one with 3 items. Then you can just set `text-align: center;` on the container.

You can add a class like `no-float` on the containers you want to control whether its children should be floated or not.

https://jsfiddle.net/bf33wc6w/10/

Comment: I thought I tried this and it didn't work. Can you update the fiddle?

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
<div id="control-buttons-container">
    <div class="col-1">
        <button class="control-button">some button text</button>
    </div>
    <div class="col-2">
        <button class="control-button">proceed with this button</button>
    </div>
    <div class="col-3">
        <button class="control-button">Seth Rollins, WWE Champion</button>
    </div>
</div>    

<div id="control-buttons-container">
    <div class="col-1">
    </div>
    <div class="col-2">
        <button class="control-button">proceed with this button</button>
    </div>
    <div class="col-3">
    </div>
</div>    




.control-button {
    background-color: #0E80B4;
    color: white;
    outline: none;
    border: none;
    float: left;
    height: 73px;
    width: 100%;
}
.control-button:hover {
    background-color: #3FA9DB;
}
#control-buttons-container {
    max-width: 400px;
    padding: 1px; 
    border: 1px solid red;
}
.col-1, .col-2, .col-3 {
    width: 32.6%;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: auto
}
```

Isn't flawless, but it was made in a couple of minutes and gets the job done: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bf33wc6w/9/)

Answer (score 0):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/114549/2827555) will probably help you out. Wrap your buttons in a container, give it a fixed width, and change `margin` to `auto`. Be sure to remove `float: left`.